# Flutter InAppWebView: supportZoom no longer works after android update

Tags: flutter, webview, zooming, flutter-web, flutter-inappwebview

I wrote an application that uses InAppWebView to display a web page, the web page zoom must be disabled, according to the specifications I set supportzoom as follows

```
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                supportZoom: false,
                clearCache: true,
                preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP))
```

Everything worked fine until the latest android update (ANDROID 11 VERSION T725XXU2DVG3/T250XM2DVB2/T725XXU2DVB2)

After the update I am able to zoom the displayed page despite the settings that worked before.

I currently use the version "flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1"

I also tried to use the beta 6.0.0 (obviously changing the deprecated methods) but nothing has changed.
I wrote a test application and it gives me the same problem

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

 
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        supportZoom: false,
        clearCache: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));
  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;

  String url = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Wakelock.enable();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
            webViewController?.reload();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InAppWebView(
        key: webViewKey,
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: Uri.parse("https://someURL")),
       
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          webViewController = controller;
        },

        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                supportZoom: false,
                clearCache: true,
                preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP)),

        onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
          setState(() {
            this.url = url.toString();
            //urlController.text = this.url;
          });
        },
        androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
          return PermissionRequestResponse(
              resources: resources,
              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
        },
        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
          var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

          if (![
            "http",
            "https",
            "file",
            "chrome",
            "data",
            "javascript",
            "about"
          ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
            if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
              // Launch the App
              await launchUrl(
                Uri.parse(url),
              );
              // and cancel the request
              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
            }
          }

          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
        },
        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
          setState(() {
            this.url = url.toString();
            //urlController.text = this.url;
          });
        },
        
        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
          if (progress == 100) {
            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
          }
          setState(() {
          
          });
        },
        onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
          setState(() {
            this.url = url.toString();
            
          });
        },
        onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
          return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
              action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
        },
        onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
          print(consoleMessage);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1
wakelock: ^0.6.2
url_launcher: ^6.1.6

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

uses-material-design: true

compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 17

Anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).